# command line to open a window

Tags: linux, shell, unix, debian

using command line, how can i open a window containing the folder?

I am looking for a unix command similar to Mac:

```
$> open /tmp
```

That command will open /tmp in an (UI) window.

So what's the equivalent in linux? I am currently using Debian.

Comment: To open the directory you are currently in: `nautilus .`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ubuntu, with Gnome, you'd do

```
nautilus /tmp
```

Under KDE, I guess you'd do

```
konqueror /tmp
```

[This blog post](http://opseast.wordpress.com/2007/07/15/file-managers-alternatives-to-nautilus-and-konqueror/) talks about alternatives to nautilus and konqueror.

Answer (score 10):

To open a folder (or any type of file/URL) with the preferred application in a Desktop Environment independent way, use [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html):

```
xdg-open /tmp
```